# How come I cannot ask a question?

Tags: support, tags, asking-questions

Looking at the privileges list, it looks like I should be able to ask questions along with answering them. However I get a red box on the right, telling me what questions are desired and how to format. Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug/downtime?

Comment: Your profile is not blocked from asking questions. Does the red box come up when you try to submit the question? If so it is providing guidance on question quality - have you tried following the guidance by updating your question?

Comment: Yes. I added &lt;code&gt; tags, spaced it out with more newlines, and it looks plenty good to me. It would be great if the guidance could single out the actual problem.

Comment: the guidance is automated, so it has some heuristic rules but its actual intelligence is limited.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2vfbtRf9 ?

Comment: That looks like it should work - and you have a title along the lines of "Does TEA require 32 rounds?" - I can't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: can you take a screen grab when you try to post the question and get the error message so we can see what is happening

Comment: Thanks for looking! http://imgur.com/LO0gSOp

Comment: @blah44, what happens when you click the red button that says "Post Your Question"

Comment: @MikePennington - nothing! Page refreshes and looks the same when finished loading.

Answer (score 5):

Given your screenshot, you're attempting to post a question with the tags [tea](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tea) and [feistel](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feistel), which do not exist. [Creating tags](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) requires 300 reputation points.

The boxes on the right are shown to everyone. They're guidance, not error messages. Pay attention to the actual error message when you attempt to submit the question:

> Creating the new tags 'tea feistel' requires at least 300 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead.

---

A question that requires specific tags such as [tea](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tea) and [feistel](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feistel) is too specialized for this site. Questions on the design and implementation techniques of cryptographic algorithms are suitable for [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/). Questions on the actual coding belong on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Your question is borderline; most questions on the Cryptography site contain math rather than code, but since your question is focuses on modifying the algorithm rather than on a coding issue, it is more suitable for Cryptography.

Be sure to use the proper formatting tool: despite its name, `<code>` is not a very good tag to use for code, since it doesn't format the content verbatim. Use 4-space indentation for literal formatting (as used by the `{}` button or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut), or `<pre>` tags. Pay attention to the preview below the editor window (which you've shrunk down to be practically empty, drag the bottom of the editor window up to make more room for the preview), make sure it comes out right. Another formatting tip: don't use bare URLs, hyperlink some English text, like `[TEA source from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm)` (which renders as [TEA source from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm)).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Aha! Thanks much. It seems like "need more rep to add a tag" could be singled out and listed as an error, which would help this situation.

Comment: @blah44 The error *is* shown — I reproduced your question while not logged in and copy-pasted the message. It appears in a sort of bubble next to the tag entry box.

Comment: huh, maybe safari is being silly. Ah well, sorry for all the noise!